# Context Free Grammar Nested Brackets, Closing With A Possible ']'

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

I am relatively new to CFG and am wondering if one of you might be able to help me determine if the current solution I have is correct. I was asked to generate the context free grammar which accepts the language of nested brackets such that if the last token is a right square bracket, it closes all remaining open left brackets.

Some examples of those strings accepted would be: (((], (()(] (()())
Some examples of those strings not accepted would be: (]), )(, ())

At current my grammar is as follows:

- S -> epsilon
- S -> ()
- S -> (]
- S -> (S)
- S -> (S]
- S -> (S
- S -> SS

From all the examples I have tried, including those listed as both accepted and non accepted states above, I think that my CFG is correct. I'm wondering if there is any way to check this more concretely than simply randomly trying a large number of possibilities, and or if any of you can spot any errors?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I believe I have found the desired solution, though again I could be wrong. Starting with the base cases for the problem I have:

- S->(]
- S->(()]
- S->()(]

From my inductive step

- S->(I]
- S->(I()]
- S->((I)]
- S->(()I]
- S->(I)(]
- S->()I(]
- S->()(I]
- I->()
- I->II
- I->(
- I->(I)

Comment: Your grammar also accepts `((])`, which should be forbidden because the ] already closes all (.

Comment: CFGs allow multiple, distinct nonterminals. You may find that useful.

Comment: @JakeMitchell could you explain and or provide a small example?

Comment: @user3277807 He's saying you can use non-terminals other than `S`. Like `S -> (X), X -> ...`.

Answer (score 2):

The second and third productions are redundant because of the first production (so the fourth and fifth productions will derive `()` and `(]`, respectively).

However, your grammar will derive, for example, `(((` (repeatedly using production 6 and then production 1), so it does not only recognize the desired language.

Comment: What if I were to remove the first production. Then, both the third and fourth production would still be required and not redundant, and in addition `ccc` would no longer be recognized by the grammar?

Comment: Yes, but `((()` would be accepted. You need to find a recursive characterization of the language. You can't solve problems like this with randomly adding and removing productions.

Comment: So if I were to consider the case of only nested parenthesis I could have the following productions:

 - S -> ()
 - S -> (S)
 - S -> SS

My main issue is how to account for the possibility that open brackets are allowed but must be closed by a single square bracket ']'. Perhaps you could help me to develop the recursive characterization for this case?

Comment: A simple characterization is that it consists of an unbalanced string followed by a close bracket. Here, by unbalanced I mean more opens than closes. Note that every unbalanced string has a unique first unmatched open parenthesis. That should be sufficient hints.

Comment: By the way, to generate balanced strings: `S -> ε`; `S -> ( S ) S` , which is deterministic. Not that that matters for this exercise, but it is useful to think about: the first open has a unique close.

Comment: I believe I have found the desired solution, though again I could be wrong.

Starting with the base cases for the problem I have:
S->(]
S->(()]
S->`()(]`

From my inductive step
`S->(I]`
`S->(I()]`
`S->((I)]`
`S->(()I]`

`S->`(I)(]`
`S->`()I(]`
`S->`()(I]`

`I->()`
`I->II`
`I->(`
`I->(I)`

Comment: Since in that grammar every S ends with ], it cannot be complete. But it is all waaaaay too complicated. The solution has maybe six productions total. (One of them is an epsilon production.)